# How to make an object appears with mousePress and stay on the screen?

Tags: java

(new to java). So I am have created the following script and I would like my object called "site" to appear only when the mouse is pressed and then stay on the screen. Then at every mouse pressed it created a new "site".

What it does now is that it creates a site at the beginning and the adds one when the mouse is pressed. But I don't want that site in the beginning, I just want it when I click.

Is anyone could help me that would be great!

```
/*preload = "factory_12.png";*/
/*preload = "sign.png";*/
/*preload = "simple_truck.png";*/

Lorry lorry;

PImage concretePlant;
PFont aFont;
int xCoord;
int yCoord;
ArrayList<Site> sites;
int siteSize = 30;

void setup() // What is called once at the beginning
{
  size (500, 500);

  concretePlant = loadImage("factory_12.png");
  aFont = createFont("IndustrialRevolution-Regular", 12);
  textFont(aFont);

  xCoord = int(width/2);
  yCoord = int(height/2);

  //Creating empty Array List where store sites objects
  sites = new ArrayList<Site>();

  //Adding first site
  sites.add(new Site(random(width), random(height), siteSize));

  //storing lorries
  lorry = new Lorry(xCoord, yCoord);
}

void draw() // Draw the background and concrete plant
{
  background (235, 247, 255); //light blue background, not in draw as it wouldn't allow the site image to stay
  image(concretePlant, xCoord, yCoord, 60, 60);
  fill(1);
  text("Concrete Plant", xCoord-20, yCoord+70);

  //Calling the sites
  for (int i = sites.size () - 1; i>=0; i--) {
    Site site = sites.get(i);
    site.displaySites();
  }

  //calling the lorry functions
    lorry.updateLorry();
}

void mousePressed() {
  sites.add(new Site(mouseX, mouseY, siteSize));
}

class Site

{
  float x,y;
  float size;
  PImage picture;

  Site (float xin, float yin, float sin)
  {
    x = xin;
    y = yin;
    size = sin;
    picture = loadImage("sign.png");
  }

  void displaySites()
  {
    image(picture, x, y, 60, 60);
  }
}

class Lorry
{
  PVector location;
  PVector concretePlant;
  PVector velocity;
  PImage mixer;
  boolean changeDirection;
  int siteNumber = 0;
  Site destination;

  Lorry(float xCoord, float yCoord)
  {
    concretePlant = new PVector(xCoord, yCoord); //Initial start point
    location = new PVector(xCoord, yCoord); //Initial start point
    velocity = new PVector(2, 2);
    mixer = loadImage("simple_truck.png");
    destination = sites.get(siteNumber);
    changeDirection = false;
  }

  void displayLorry()
  {
    image(mixer, location.x, location.y, 30, 30);
  }

  void Move()
  {
    float xdir = destination.x - location.x;
    float ydir = destination.y - location.y;
    PVector dir = new PVector (xdir, ydir);
    dir.normalize();

    location.add(dir);
    print("going");
  }

  void reachDestination()
  {
    //println(destination,location);
    //if ((destination.x == location.x) && (destination.y == location.y)) {
    if (dist(destination.x, destination.y, location.x, location.y) < 1) {

      if (siteNumber <sites.size() -1) {
        siteNumber++; // siteNumber = siteNumber + 1;
        destination = sites.get(siteNumber);
        changeDirection = true;
      } else {
        println("reached final site");
      }
      println("reachedDestination");
    }
  }

  void updateLorry()
  {
    displayLorry();
    Move();
    reachDestination();
  }
}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this line:

```
//Adding first site
sites.add(new Site(random(width), random(height), siteSize));
```

This line in your `setup()` function adds a `Site`. If you don't want to add a `Site` at startup, remove this line.

You should also try to go through the process of [debugging your problem](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging). For example, step through the code line-by-line with a piece of paper and a pencil, or add print statements, or use the debugger that comes with the Processing editor. That will help you figure out problems like this in the future. Good luck!

Comment: When I remove that line all my object from the screen disappears. All I have that remains is the font I have inserted and the color of the background.

Comment: @Lilly Isn't that exactly what you want to happen? Please note that I'm only talking about the call to `sites.add()` inside the `setup()` function. I'm not talking about the call inside the `mousePressed()` function.